# Using TLS 1.2 on .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, tls1.2

Is there any way to force my .net 6.0 application to use TLS 1.2? Im sadly forced to use TLS 1.2 by an API that is yet to be updated and i would prefer to not make a lot of loopholes to run 4.7/4.8 just to get TLS 1.2.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338951/tls-v1-2-cipher-suites-in-net-6-get-request-timeout

Comment: D A is right. TLS 1.2 is the default. Most likely problem is you don't have matching cypher suites to match your destination https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677592/283895